# SM-BB51 Replacment

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket

I have an oldish bike around 8 years old.

My bottom bracket has started to make a clunking/clicking sound.

It currently has a SM-BB51 fitted.
I'm unable to find a exact replacement in stock. I'm taking it is now end of life.

What other bottom bracket could I replace the SM-BB51 with?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Before you blame the bottom bracket, take off the pedals and grease the axle threads... It has been more than once that I though the bb has gone bad and it turned to be just pedals...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hello and welcome to bicycles.stackexchange.com

You will struggle to find components in stock anywhere right now given the global component shortage + covid.

As to your question, compatible parts are...

From Shimano:

- **SM-BB52** - Deore level component. Direct successor of your SM-BB51
- **SM-BB70** - SLX level component
- **BB-MT800** - XT level compoment. You will need a different tool or an adapter. I've recently replaced my SM-BB52 with BB-MT800. See this thread: [SM-BB52 vs BB-MT800](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/71497/13579)
- **SM-BB80** - Saint level component
- **SM-BB-93** - XTR level component. Nuff said

If you choose to go with other manufacturers you can grab anything that conforms to all of the following three standards:

- 24mm spindle diameter
- BSA threaded
- 68/73mm width to match your frame

Good luck!